# Texture maps appear black in WebGL examples

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am using an ebook guide "WebGL up-and-running" to learn WebGL. The ebook has an accompanying repository on GitHub to run some examples. The examples work fine (animation, shape, camera movement, etc.) when I run them except the textures aren't right (most appear black while others don't appear in the browser). The problem doesn't lie with the code (I think) as I didn't touch it since downloading from GitHub. 
The only instruction from the guide that I didn't follow is a single paragraph that states:

"Finally, get all of this onto a web server. You will need to serve up your pages in order for most of the samples in the book to work. I run a local version of a standard LAMP stack on my MacBook…but all you really need is the “A” part of LAMP (i.e., a web server such as Apache)."

I have no idea what a web server does in this context and don't know how to install it. Could this be the problem? If so please assist me in getting started with a web server. If not, what else could cause the example models not to render properly?

When I run examples from https://threejs.org/examples all of them work fine.

Comment: There is actually a guide in the official `three.js` documentation that explains how to run things locally in order to avoid security issues in the browser. Give the `node.js` solution a try and see if it solves your problem: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the command line you can also use [this server](https://greggman.github.io/servez/)

Comment: @Mugen87 - You were right, that was the problem. I managed with Servez, recommended by gman. Thanks.

Comment: @gman - Servez worked a charm. Thanks.